# Use intellij on PC as working environment for laptop

Tags: intellij-idea

I've laptop and PC at home. I would like to use my PC which is much stronger that than laptop as working environment for my laptop. 
PC works on ubuntu, I've configured and connected ftp server but have no idea how could it work ofc I can compare my local files etc but what if I need to run tests or change git branch. Should I do it via terminal and ssh? Its quite unintuitive. May you know or use any software which enables you to work on laptop but use PC/remote server power for calculations.

Comment: and team-viewer is not an option? (eg. used your laptop and login into your pc via remote?)

Comment: its kind of but I though about something more complex that is built in intellij